# Не отображаются данные с формы отправки. На имейл приходит письмо но оно пустое

Tags: php

Помогите пожалуйста. Не пойму в чем причина. Фома работает так: приходит письмо, но данные с переменных в ней не отображаются. Таким образом оно пустое. Может кто подскажет в чем дело

```
$mails = array('@mail');
define('MAIL_SUBJECT', 'Тема');

$headers   = array();
$headers[] = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
$headers[] = "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8";
$headers[] = "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion();

(isset($_POST['name'])) ? $name = 'Имя клиента: ' . htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']) . "\n": $name = '';
(isset($_POST['phone'])) ? $phone = 'Телефон заказчика: ' . htmlspecialchars($_POST['phone']) . "\n": $phone = '';
(isset($_POST['email'])) ? $email = 'E-mail заказчика: ' . htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']) . "\n": $email = '';
(isset($_POST['from'])) ? $from = 'Форма: ' . htmlspecialchars($_POST['from']) . "\n": $from = '';

$result = true;

foreach ($mails as $val) {
    if (!mail($val, MAIL_SUBJECT, $name . $phone . $email . $from, implode("\r\n", $headers))) {
        $result = false;
        break;
    }
}

if ($result) { 
    header('Location: thanks.html');
    exit;
}
```

Comment: а var_dump($_POST) что говорит?

Comment: Так же "Каждая строка должна быть отделена символом CRLF (\r\n). Строки не должны быть длиннее 70 символов.", а у вас "\n". Но дело не в этом скорее всего

Comment: спасибо, но не помогло

Comment: У вас что-то не так с $_POST, возможно он пустым приходит, так как скрипт написан верно и данные отправляются корректно, если они есть конечно.